# Deleting table from Azure

Tags: sql, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to delete a table from Azure Database but I am not able to accomplish this as I am getting an error when I drop that table

### Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

Kindly help, 
Thanx in Advance.

Comment: make sure no other operation manipulating the table(insert/update/delete) as it might be deadlock happend

Comment: I tried to delete other tables too but none of them is getting deleted in azure. What could be the issue?

Comment: http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jlane/deleting-entities-in-windows-azure-table-storage

Here’s the problem, in a nutshell. Azure Tables don’t support the SQL equivalent of this:
delete * from MyTable where ...

maybe you can post some of your code, it helps other to identify your issuse